# Can Interferometery be Used to Shorten the Solar Gravitational Lens Focal

Tags: gravity, space-telescope

The solar gravitational lens's focal is around 550 AU which is very far. Can we send a few telescopes that will stop midway (let's assume 150 AU) to collect the light and work as interferometry?

Comment: Interesting question! Different but somewhat related: [What might the first deep space telescope using the Sun or Jupiter as a gravitational lens be like?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/31815/12102)